# FFMPEG extract clip and fade in and out

Tags: ffmpeg

I can't seem to figure out how to extract audio at the 45 second mark for a duration of 30 seconds, and fade in and out for 2 seconds. This is what I have, but I cannot get it working.

```
ffmpeg -y -i $ORIGINAL -ab 64 $STREAM
ffmpeg -y -i $STREAM -ss 00:00:45 -t 00:00:30 $CLIP
ffmpeg -y -i $CLIP -af "afade=t=in:ss=0:d=2,afade=t=out:st=28:d=2" $CLIP
```

(The $STREAM file is supposed to be different than the $CLIP file)

What I end up with is a 2 second clip.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If your third command indicates that the output file is the same as your input file, there's your problem. FFmpeg does not do in-place editing. The output file has to be different.

Anyway, you can do it in one go, avoiding generational loss

```
ffmpeg -y -i $ORIGINAL \
       -af "atrim=45:duration=30,asetpts=N/SR/TB,afade=in:d=2,afade=out:st=28:d=2" \
       -ab 64k $TRIMMED
```